# Moving right to left using animate in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to animate the form using its ID to move rihgt to left. I already tried code bellow but this doesnt move the form content at all. Whats wrong i am doing here? Note: I am using Bootstrap v3.4.1

Html Code:

```js
$("#formContent").css({ "left": "2000px" }).animate({ "left": "0px" }, "slow");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h1><span id="firstLineTxt"></span></h1>
    <h1><span id="secondLineTxt"></span></h1>

    <div id="formContent">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="fullname" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Let's Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whether it works or not will largely depend on your css, specifically the container (.col in your case).   row/col look like bootstrap classes, please tag which version of bootstrap and (ideally) include them in a snippet.

Comment: `left` of course only works, if the element is somehow positioned to begin with (`position` set with any other value than the default, `static`) And rather than changing positioning values, you should apply a `translate` transformation to begin with, that is much better for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As left only works on positioned elements, you could animate the translateX instead. It would also be better to use a css transition rather than using a jquery animation:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#formContent").addClass('animate');
})
```

```css
#formContent {
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}

#formContent.animate {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h1><span id="firstLineTxt"></span></h1>
    <h1><span id="secondLineTxt"></span></h1>

    <div id="formContent">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="fullname" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Let's Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you didn't want to use jquery at all, you could just use a keyframes animation:

```css
#formContent {
  animation: 2s forwards alternate slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }

  to {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h1><span id="firstLineTxt"></span></h1>
    <h1><span id="secondLineTxt"></span></h1>

    <div id="formContent">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="fullname" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Let's Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```